# Why can't I auto deref when reading from a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, dereference

I got this question from [Rustling](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings):

```
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for element in v.iter_mut() {
        *element = *element * 2;
    }

    v
}
```

`vec_loop` multiplies the elements in `v` by 2 in place. But I'm not sure why I can't write it like this:

```
*element = element * 2;
```

I got the compiler error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot multiply `&mut i32` by `{integer}`
  --> exercises/vecs/vecs2.rs:14:28
   |
14 |         *element = element * 2;
   |                    ------- ^ - {integer}
   |                    |
   |                    &mut i32
   |
help: `*` can be used on `i32` if you dereference the left-hand side
   |
14 |         *element = *element * 2;
   |                    +
```

As far as I know, a `&i32` reference can be auto dereferenced for reading. Why can't `&mut i32`?

For example, another function from the same Rustling:

```
fn vec_map(v: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.iter().map(|element| {
        element * 2
    }).collect()
}
```

In this case the auto defer works. No need to write `*element * 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an implementation of `Mul` for `&i32 * i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html#impl-Mul%3Ci32%3E-for-%26%27a+i32) which is why the second example works. However `&i32` and `&mut i32` are distinct types and while the latter can be [*coerced*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) into the former, coercions are not applied when deducing trait implementations like for `Mul`.

So because there is no implementation for `&mut i32 * i32`, you must explicitly dereference or reborrow the `element`: `*element * 2` or `&*element * 2`.

Comment: I see. So is it correct to say actually no auto deference happens in `element * 2` in the second example?

Comment: @Kodra correct, there is no auto dereference happening